# Cannot read property snapshot of undefined webpack storybook

Tags: reactjs, storybook, monorepo, webpack-5

I have created monorepo using yarn workspace which have two microfrontends app developed using webpack module federation and one ui lib application which has storybook also. When I am trying to run storybook in monorepo, it is giving below error

Cannot read property 'createSnapshot' of undefined
at/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/webpack5/file-watcher-api.js

When I am running my ui lib outside of monorepo, it is running fine, but when I am including ui lib as part of monorepo, it is hoisting node modules and started using webpack5 which is causing an issue. I am not able to figure it out how to make it work. I don't want to create polyrepo as then sharing ui lib become bit tedious but because of storybook and ui lib sharing I want to go with monorepo but it is causing an issue.

Comment: This question lacks specifics to answer it. I personally don't experience problems with a similar configuration. Installing the latest version of html-webpack-plugin might help. If it does not, you might try to workaround the problem with nohoist feature of yarn (https://classic.yarnpkg.com/blog/2018/02/15/nohoist/)

Comment: Thanks @AMakarov for your answer, I made it work by specifying nohoist config  like "nohoist": ["**"] , but it applies for entire dependency. I want to restrict it to fewer packages which is causing issue like html webpack plugin. By default it goes and start using webpack5 in its lib. It has webpack 4 also but somehow it doesn't use webpack4